# Error Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I want to create one where uploading images or uploading files is not necessary.

When I don't include the image file an error like this " **Error Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null**". I want file upload to be optional

I'm new to laravel, so can anyone help me?

this error in here :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcAmi.jpg)

code in : public function storeproduk(Request $request) and public function updateproduk(Request $request, $id)

source code

**ProdukController (insert)**

```
public function storeproduk(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [

        'anggota_id' => 'required',
        'produk_unggulan' => 'required',
        'sosial' => 'required',
        'lingkungan' => 'required',
        // 'fotoone' => 'required|nullable|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:3048',
        // 'fototwo' => 'required|nullable|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:3048',
    ], $messages = [
        'anggota_id.required' => 'Nama Anggota Tidak Boleh Kosong dan Wajib Diisi',
        'produk_unggulan.required' => 'Produk Unggulan Tidak Boleh Kosong dan Wajib Diisi',
        'sosial.required' => 'Kemanfaatan Sosial Tidak Boleh Kosong dan Wajib Diisi',
        'lingkungan.required' => 'Kemanfaatan Lingkungan Tidak Boleh Kosong dan Wajib Di isi',
        // 'fotoone.required' => 'Foto #1 tidak boleh kosong | Pilih Foto Terlebih Dahulu',
        // 'fototwo.required' => 'Foto #2 tidak boleh kosong | Pilih Foto Terlebih Dahulu',
    ]);

    $nm = $request->fotoone;
    $namaFile = $nm->getClientOriginalName();

    $nm2 = $request->fototwo;
    $namaFile2 = $nm2->getClientOriginalName();

    $data = Produk::create([

        'anggota_id' => $request->anggota_id,
        'produk_unggulan' => $request->produk_unggulan,

        'jenis_sayur' => $request->jenis_sayur,
        'nama_sayur' => $request->nama_sayur,
        'kg_sayur' => $request->kg_sayur,
        'total_sayur' => $request->total_sayur,

        'jenis_buah' => $request->jenis_buah,
        'nama_buah' => $request->nama_buah,
        'kg_buah' => $request->kg_buah,
        'total_buah' => $request->total_buah,

        'jenis_ikan' => $request->jenis_ikan,
        'nama_ikan' => $request->nama_ikan,
        'kg_ikan' => $request->kg_ikan,
        'total_ikan' => $request->total_ikan,

        'jenis_ternak' => $request->jenis_ternak,
        'nama_ternak' => $request->nama_ternak,
        'kg_ternak' => $request->kg_ternak,
        'total_ternak' => $request->total_ternak,

        'sosial' => $request->sosial,
        'lingkungan' => $request->lingkungan,
        'fotoone' => $request->fotoone = $namaFile,
        'fototwo' => $request->fototwo = $namaFile2,
    ]);

    //BamaraID
    // $nm = $request->fotoone;
    // $namaFile = $nm->getClientOriginalName();

    // $nm2 = $request->fototwo;
    // $namaFile2 = $nm2->getClientOriginalName();

    // $dtUpload = new Produk;
    // $dtUpload->fotoone = $namaFile;
    // $dtUpload->fototwo = $namaFile2;

    $nm->move(public_path() . '/img', $namaFile);
    $nm2->move(public_path() . '/img', $namaFile2);

    // if ($request->file('fotoone')) {
    //     $request->file('fotoone')->move('public/fotoproduksi/', $request->file('fotoone')->getClientOriginalName());
    //     $data->fotoone = $request->file('fotoone')->getClientOriginalName();
    // }
    // if ($request->file('fototwo')) {
    //     $request->file('fototwo')->move('public/fotoproduksi/', $request->file('fototwo')->getClientOriginalName());
    //     $data->fototwo = $request->file('fototwo')->getClientOriginalName();
    // }

    $data->save();

    return redirect('/dashboard/produk')->with('success', 'Data Berhasil Ditambahkan!');
}
```

**ProdukController (update)**

```
public function updateproduk(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [

        'fotoone' => 'required',
        'fototwo' => 'required',
    ], $messages = [
        'fotoone.required' => 'Foto #1 tidak boleh kosong | Pilih Foto Terlebih Dahulu',
        'fototwo.required' => 'Foto #2 tidak boleh kosong | Pilih Foto Terlebih Dahulu',
    ]);

    $dats = Produk::find($id);
    $awal = $dats->fotoone;
    $awal2 = $dats->fototwo;

    $dt = [
        'produk_unggulan' => $request['produk_unggulan'],
        'nama_sayur' => $request['nama_sayur'],
        'kg_sayur' => $request['kg_sayur'],
        'total_sayur' => $request['total_sayur'],
        'nama_buah' => $request['nama_buah'],
        'kg_buah' => $request['kg_buah'],
        'total_buah' => $request['total_buah'],
        'nama_ikan' => $request['nama_ikan'],
        'kg_ikan' => $request['kg_ikan'],
        'total_ikan' => $request['total_ikan'],
        'nama_ternak' => $request['nama_ternak'],
        'kg_ternak' => $request['kg_ternak'],
        'total_ternak' => $request['total_ternak'],
        'sosial' => $request['sosial'],
        'lingkungan' => $request['lingkungan'],
        'fotoone' => $awal,
        'fototwo' => $awal2,
    ];

    $request->fotoone->move(public_path() . '/img', $awal);
    $request->fototwo->move(public_path() . '/img', $awal2);

    $dats->update($dt);

    // $dats->update($request->all());

    // if ($request->file('fotoone')) {
    //     $request->file('fotoone')->move('public/fotoproduksi/', $request->file('fotoone')->getClientOriginalName());
    //     $dats->fotoone = $request->file('fotoone')->getClientOriginalName();
    // }
    // if ($request->file('fototwo')) {
    //     $request->file('fototwo')->move('public/fotoproduksi/', $request->file('fototwo')->getClientOriginalName());
    //     $dats->fototwo = $request->file('fototwo')->getClientOriginalName();
    // }

    // $dats->save();

    return redirect('/dashboard/produk')->with('success', 'Data Berhasil Di Update!');
}
```

}

**View :**

```
 <form action="{{ route('storeproduk') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf

<div class="form-group">
                                <label for="fotoone">Foto Produk #1</label>
                                {{-- @error('fotoone')
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                                @enderror --}}
                                <input type="file" id="fotoone" name="fotoone" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="fototwo">Foto Produk #2</label>
                                {{-- @error('fototwo')
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                                @enderror --}}
                                <input type="file" id="fototwo" name="fototwo" class="form-control">
                            </div>
```

Comment: error in : $namaFile = $nm->getClientOriginalName();

Comment: use `$request->hasFile` to determine if the file is uploaded. Do file related stuff after that. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files  Also would be a good idea to determine file extension from mime type of the uploaded file instead of depending on client extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$nm = $request->file('fotoone');
$namaFile = '';
if ($nm) {
   $name = $nm->getClientOriginalName();
   $extension = $nm->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $namaFile = $name . '.' . $extension;
}

$nm2 = $request->file('fototwo');
$namaFile2 = '';
if ($nm2) {
   $name = $nm2->getClientOriginalName();
   $extension = $nm2->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $namaFile2 = $name . '.' . $extension;
}
```

Comment: I have tried but it still shows the error in the section: $namaFile = $nm->getClientOriginalName();

Comment: Could you give me more details about ```form``` that you are using ?

Comment: I have updated in the post above

Comment: your code works but still new problem appears like this "Call to a member function move() on null". in code : $nm->move(public_path() . '/img', $namaFile); and
        $nm2->move(public_path() . '/img', $namaFile2);